# Testing a databaseless Rails 5 application with rspec-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, no-database

I have a Rails `5.0.1` app that is NOT backed by any database. When attempting to write a controller test I get a `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished` exception even though I have explicitly configured my `spec/rails_helper.rb` not to use `ActiveRecord` and removed references to active_record in `config/application.rb`. RSpec is trying to run such test within a transaction which requires a database connection to be established. I am attaching the stack trace for reference and I used this Github issue to setup RSpec without `ActiveRecord` [rspec-rails for a rails project without db connection](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1416#issuecomment-120055707).

Failures:

1) ApplicationController the truth false not equal true
     Failure/Error: raise ConnectionNotEstablished, "No connection pool with id #{spec_name} found." unless pool

```
 ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished:
   No connection pool with id primary found.
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `retrieve_connection'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:128:in `retrieve_connection'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:91:in `connection'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:516:in `create_fixtures'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:1015:in `load_fixtures'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:988:in `setup_fixtures'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:852:in `before_setup'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.6.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:375:in `execute_with'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:606:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:342:in `call'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:607:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:464:in `run'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `with_around_example_hooks'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:500:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:251:in `run'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:627:in `block in run_examples'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `map'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `run_examples'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:589:in `run'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `block in run'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `map'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `run'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `map'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1894:in `with_suite_hooks'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block in run_specs'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:79:in `report'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `run_specs'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:87:in `run'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
 # /home/vagrant/.bundle/easypost_admin/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<top (required)>'
 # /opt/ruby2.3/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
 # /opt/ruby2.3/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
 # /opt/ruby2.3/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:24:in `run'
 # /opt/ruby2.3/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:304:in `exec'
 # /opt/ruby2.3/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
 # /opt/ruby2.3/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
 # /opt/ruby2.3/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
 # /opt/ruby2.3/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
 # /opt/ruby2.3/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
 # /opt/ruby2.3/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
 # /opt/ruby2.3/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in `with_friendly_errors'
 # /opt/ruby2.3/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:19:in `<top (required)>'
 # /vagrant/easypost_admin/vendor/bundle/bundle:23:in `load'
 # /vagrant/easypost_admin/vendor/bundle/bundle:23:in `<main>'
 #
 #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
 #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
 #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
```

Finished in 0.0058 seconds (files took 2.29 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb:15 # ApplicationController the truth false not equal true

**UPDATE**

`rails_help.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Checks for pending migration and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
# ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

`spec_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end
```

Comment: Could you show us your _spec_helper.rb_ and _rails_helper.rb_?

Comment: Did you change `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` to false in `rails_helper.rb`?

Comment: @Leito I updated my question to include `rails_helper.rb` and `spec_helper.rb`. @mindlis yes `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` it set to false.

Answer (score 10):

I had the very same issue with a rails 5.2.0.alpha app without a database
configured. So I had a look at the rspec-rails code, and figured out this
line which causes all the trouble:

[rspec-rails/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb#L5):

```
if defined?(ActiveRecord::TestFixtures)
```

It checks for a loaded ActiveRecord constant, which actually was loaded.  I
also had `require 'active_record/railtie'` commented out from
`config/application.rb`.  Then I figured out who required the ActiveStorage gem
(bundle.lock). In my case it was ActiveStorage.

I just use the ActiveStorage functionality without a database, so I had to
remove the ActiveRecord constant on my `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

# Remove the ActiveRecord constant, because it is autloaded by
# ActiveStorage and not needed for our application. The presence
# of the ActiveRecord constant causes rspec-rails to include
# extra fixture support, which results in:
#
#   ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished:
#     No connection pool with 'primary' found.
#
Object.send(:remove_const, :ActiveRecord)
```

Mind the order, it needs to be placed after

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
```

and before

```
require 'rspec/rails'
```

This solution just modify the test environment.

#### UPDATE

I create [an issue on rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1876) which targets the creation of a global rspec configuration to turn off ActiveRecord handling.

Comment: thanks for your hack solution! I wouldn't be able to solve that so easily. And it's just sad that your issue to rspec-rails didn't get their attention  to fix the problem. For those who had the same problem, I'm using Rails 5.2 and Rspec-rails 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

A [fix for this](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/2266/files#diff-4e96817c372afd018a820f9c5cc99394R50) has just been merged into `rspec-rails`, and will supposedly be released along with RSpec Rails 4.0 sometimes next week.

What you have to set the following in your `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
config.use_active_record = false
```

Again, the problem is that if you didn't configure/use the database connection, but `ActiveRecord` is still present (due to Bundler loading it or some other reasons).